# Python's datetime adding almost a whole extra hour

Tags: python, datetime

I am writing just a simple Discord bot in Python to convert a date & time to a user's timezone. This will use Discord's own time converting functionality by accepting a time in seconds and displaying it in the correct time for the user.

I wrote a function in Python that accepts a string and parses it to find any dates and times, getting the user's locale, and using that to get a datetime object. From there, I can use the datetime's `timestamp()` method to return seconds. This is where I'm encountering issues. For my local timezone (Australia/Sydney), I'm seeing 55 minutes be added to a 4pm time. If I keep the time but switch to America/New_York, I'm seeing 56 minutes added.

```
datetime(2024, 3, 14, 16, 0, 0, 0, pytz.timezone('Australia/Sydney')).timestamp()
> 1710395700.0
```

```py
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

datetime(2024, 3, 14, 16, 0, 0, 0, pytz.timezone('Australia/Sydney')).timestamp()
# 1710395700.0
```

I used JavaScript to confirm this timezone worked since that's what Discord uses. I had to multiply by 1000 since JavaScript's accepts milliseconds.

```js
new Date(1710395700000)
// Thu Mar 14 2024 16:55:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
```

You can see that 55 minutes were added. If you post `<t:1710395700>` into a Discord channel, you'll get the same result.

As I stated earlier, this happens for other timezones too but with different amounts New York adds 56 minutes. Because of this, I can't just subtract a constant value.

```py
datetime(2024, 3, 14, 16, 0, 0, 0, pytz.timezone('America/New_York')).timestamp()
# 1710449760.0
```

```js
new Date(1710449760000)
// Fri Mar 15 2024 07:56:00 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)
```

What is happening here? Is this an issue with the `timestamp()` method in the datetime library or is JavaScript not interpreting it correctly? What is the correct way to get the timestamp I want?